# Extending an interface from a third party definition file

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I'm using [this](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/sequelize/sequelize.d.ts#L2763) definition file in my Typescript code. The problem is that, according to Sequelize documentation to set the length of a string column, I should define its type as:

```
 Sequelize.STRING(20)
```

and the current definition file doesn't allow this. It allows only `Sequelize.STRING` (which makes a default column length of 255).

I want to create my own definition file, patching (extending) this interface so that it supports both situations, or at least setting Sequelize.STRING as `any` so that I don't get compiler errors.

Any idea how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix at :

```
    interface DataTypeString extends DataTypeStringBase {
        (length?:number): any; // ADD this 
    }
```

A PR + TEST would be appreciated :)

## Update

> Would it be possible somehow to implement this in my own .d.ts file, extending the provided one?

**FAILED ATTEMPT**
Untested but probably correct:

```
declare module "sequelize"
{
  module sequelize {
     interface DataTypeString {
            (length?:number): any;
     }
  }
}
```

## Update 2

Based on how the definition is currently written you can't extend it externally https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2784

Comment: I understand how to fix the provided d.ts file, (and I will send a PR). But I'm also trying to understand how declaration merging works in Typescript. Would it be possible somehow to implement this in my own .d.ts file, extending the provided one?. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Now I get TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. I think the problem here is that the sequelize.d.ts is exporting just a variable, so my own .d.ts cannot have access to anything else. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: So, the full error list for the updated approach myfile.ts(12,23): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. typings/sequelize/sequelize.d.ts(2787,5): error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.

Comment: I sort of expected that and therefore put in *Untested*. So yeah ... in short you can't *based on how the definition is currently written*.

Comment: The TS issue was fixed. Is it possible now?